# Error running make:request on laravel 5

Tags: laravel

When running the example code on the laravel docs `php artisan make:request StoreBlogPostRequest` to create a new validation controller, I get the following error

```
[RuntimeException]                       
Unable to detect application namespace.
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, I've done some searching, but nothing really explains this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Laravel 5, an "application" is a collection of PHP files under a single namespace, stored in the folder `app/`

By default, and in most of the Laravel 5 sample code from the docs, this namespace is `App\`.  For example, one controller in  your application might look like this.

```
namespace App\Http\Controller;
class MyController
{
    //...
}
```

When Laravel generates code (i.e. when you use the `make:request` command), it needs to know what this application namespace is (it's possible to change the namespace with the `artisan app:name` command).  For some reason, in your system, Laravel 5 can't detect the namespace.

If you look at the section of Laravel 5 core code that detects the namespace

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/AppNamespaceDetectorTrait.php
protected function getAppNamespace()
{
    $composer = json_decode(file_get_contents(base_path().'/composer.json'), true);

    foreach ((array) data_get($composer, 'autoload.psr-4') as $namespace => $path)
    {
        foreach ((array) $path as $pathChoice)
        {
            if (realpath(app_path()) == realpath(base_path().'/'.$pathChoice)) return $namespace;
        }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to detect application namespace.");
}
```

You'll see that Laravel detects the namespace by looking at your `composer.json` file, and looking for thefirst valid `psr-4` namespace.

My guess is your `composer.json` file is missing the namespace

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Add that back in, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: in my case app exists in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error can be mapped to syntax issues or errors in composer.json file. Check for any trailing commas or Auto load issue. For e.g.

```
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.5",        
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5",
},
```

This should be..

```
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.5",        
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
},
```

See no trailing commas at the end of  "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"